# Which characters are allowed in iPhone app name

Tags: iphone, app-store

I discovered I probably should rename my app. What characters are allowed in the name? I have searched for the list of restricted characters but have found none.

A second question. Apparently the simulator won't allow a slash in the name. Any workarounds (assuming / is allowed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your product name simple (not sure about the the exact rules - I stick with alphanumeric characters), but put additional characters (like '/') in the Bundle Display Name key of your Info.plist file. The name of the built file on disk will be your product name (set by the Bundle Name key), but the iPhone will show the Bundle Display Name value.

I ran into a similar problem a while back with the + character - I couldn't sign any apps with the character in the bundle name. So, I changed the name from Xxx+ to XxxPlus and set the Bundle Display Name to Xxx+. Looked like I wanted it to in the GUI and the signing worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is allowed, see attached scree cap .. [alt text http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/5462/slashs.jpg](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/5462/slashs.jpg)